# How to display string[] for creating column chart in Spring and jsp

Tags: spring, list, jsp, charts, canvasjs

I want to create a column chart, I find **CanvasJS.Chart** to create a chart but it accepts a single element for creating a chart, so my question is how can I use my **string[]** in CanvasJS.Chart for creating chart

*value* and *Nvalue* received from checkbox selection option

```
    @RequestParam(value = "value", required = false) String[] value)
   @RequestParam(value = "Nvalue", required = false) String[] Nvalue)


    String names[] = value;
    String number[] = Nvalue;


    model.addAttribute("names", names);
   model.addAttribute("umber", number);





<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>  
 <title>Basic HTML5 Column Chart </title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
      title:{
        text: "Top Oil Reserves"    
      },
      animationEnabled: true,
      axisY: {
        title: "Reserves(MMbbl)"
      },
      legend: {
        verticalAlign: "bottom",
        horizontalAlign: "center"
      },
      theme: "theme2",
      data: [

      {        
        type: "column",  
        showInLegend: true, 
        legendMarkerColor: "grey",
        legendText: "MMbbl = one million barrels",
        dataPoints: [      
        {y: 297571, label: "Venezuela"}
        ]
      }   
      ]
    });

    chart.render();
  }
  </script>
  <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.7.0/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
  <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:java]?

Answer (score 1):

```
var names=["one"," two"," tree"];
var values=[10, 20, 30];

var result=names.map(function(name,id){
  return  {y:values[id]||0, label:name};
  });
```

The result is your dataPoints array.

**Example:**

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Basic HTML5 Column Chart </title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {

      var names = ["one", " two", " tree"];
      var values = [10, 20, 30];

      var result = names.map(function(name, id) {
        return {
          y: values[id] || 0,
          label: name
        };
      });
      var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        title: {
          text: "Top Oil Reserves"
        },
        animationEnabled: true,
        axisY: {
          title: "Reserves(MMbbl)"
        },
        legend: {
          verticalAlign: "bottom",
          horizontalAlign: "center"
        },
        theme: "theme2",
        data: [

          {
            type: "column",
            showInLegend: true,
            legendMarkerColor: "grey",
            legendText: "MMbbl = one million barrels",
            dataPoints: result
          }
        ]
      });

      chart.render();
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.7.0/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for holding values pairs, I used [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to transform java objects into json strings.

```
class DataPoint {
    private String y;
    private String label;
    public DataPoint(String y, String label) {
        super();
        this.y = y;
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

Create an helper class with a static method which converts the pair of arrays into a jsonString

```
public class MyHelperClass {
    public static String toJson(String[] labels, String[] nums) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        List<DataPoint> data = new ArrayList<DataPoint>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            DataPoint dp = new DataPoint(nums[i], labels[i]);
            data.add(dp);
        }

        String jsonData = gson.toJson(data);
        return jsonData;
    }
}
```

Insert the jsonString into the jsp

```
  {        
    type: "column",  
    showInLegend: true, 
    legendMarkerColor: "grey",
    legendText: "MMbbl = one million barrels",
    dataPoints: <%= MyHelperClass.toJson(arrayA,arrayB) %>
  }
```

Eventually you will want to create some RESTful web service instead of putting logic insde the JSP.